# How to force a newly created window to the foreground?

Tags: linux, bash, kde-plasma

I'm launching apps usin gtk-launch.  The app launches, however, if another instance of the app exists, the app doesn't come to the foreground.

Is there anyway I can force the last created window to the foreground?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
open_app(){
    msg="Launching app..."
    notify-send "$msg"; echo "$msg"
    qvm-run "$execution_qube" gtk-launch "$app_path" && exit # debian qubes 
    qvm-run "$execution_qube" /usr/share/applications/"$app_path" && exit # fedora qubes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use: `wmctrl -a`.

`wmctrl -l .. a` list of all opened windows, the last opened is the last one in the list

```
wmctrl -a [winname]
```

or

```
wmctrl -ia [winidHEX]
```